# How do I revive my dying rubber plants

Tags: plant-health, plant-care

[image]

Experts please advice on saving these rubber plants.They were repotted from nursery pot almost a month back.Their roots were completely exposed as roots were badly entangled in small plastic basket sort of planters.
How can I revive them?

Comment: Are the leaves crisp or soft? What kind of soil are you using? They need well draining soil. Could be overwatering?